# Weak-strong continuous non-compact operator $c_0 \to \ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence, compact-operators

In our lecture on partial differential equations we proved the following statement

> Let $V$ be reflexive and $A: V \to V^*$ a weak-strong continuous operator ($u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $V$ $\implies A u_n \to A u$ in $V^*$). Then $A$ is compact.

In the proof the reflexivity of $V$ is essential.
Therefore, I was looking for a counterexample for this statement if we drop reflexivity, i.e. I want to find an operator $A: V \to V^*$, where $V$ is a non-reflexive Banach space which is weak-strong continuous but not compact.

The simplest non-reflexive Banach space, whose dual is not too complicated I could think of is $V = c_0$, the space of zero sequences and therefore $V^* = \ell_1$.

Any **hints** are welcome.

**Update 1:**
As noted in the comments by @DanielFisher we can rule out linear maps $A: c_0 \to \ell_1$ as [Pitt's theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-04/S0002-9939-08-09617-2/S0002-9939-08-09617-2.pdf) states all bounded linear operators $c_0 \to \ell_{p}$, $p < \infty$ are compact.

Comment: Yes, we can rule out linear $A$. Not quite by my argument, because according to Albiac/Kalton Pitt's theorem applies only to $\ell^s \to \ell^p$ with $p < s < \infty$ (the $s < \infty$ requirement isn't mentioned on wikipedia), but they state it also holds for $c_0 \to \ell^p$, and that's what we're looking at.

Comment: By "norm-continuity" I mean that the map is continuous when both spaces carry their norm topology (which is also their strong topology, since they are Banach spaces, hence barrelled). And since norm topologies are metrisable, continuity coincides with sequential continuity for maps between normed spaces. Since norm convergence of a sequence implies weak convergence, it follows that weak-strong continuity as defined here (which technically is weak-strong _sequential_ continuity) implies strong-strong continuity (= norm-continuity).

Comment: If one defines weak-strong continuity as "the preimage of every strongly open set is weakly open" (thus the map is continuous if the domain is endowed with the weak topology and the codomain with the strong topology, which implies weak-strong sequential continuity, but may be strictly more restrictive), then we have the general fact that a continuous map between topological spaces remains continuous if we endow the domain with a finer topology [or the codomain with a coarser topology].

Comment: In general it isn't, weak-strong sequential continuity of $A$ (your definition) generally doesn't imply continuity of $A \colon (V, \sigma(V,V^{\ast})) \to (V^{\ast}, b(V^{\ast},V))$ (case in point: daw's example below). Whether it's equivalent for $A \colon c_0 \to \ell^1$ I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $V=l^1$, $V^*=l^\infty$, $A=id$ the continuous embedding $l^1\hookrightarrow l^\infty$? Due to the Schur-property, it is trivially weak-strong continuous, but not compact.

Comment: The image of the unit sphere contains the sequence of unit vectors $(e_n)$, these have no convergent subsequence.